# how to call deployed smartcontract with sendRawTransaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, nodejs, ethereum-classic

with this code i want to call my token smartcontract's transfer function. as per my knowledge i have to add this ".transfer(address,amount)" to data field. am i correct? also i am using web3 0.20. in this version i have to use getData right?
 so that will be **var dataforTx = mycontract.tranfer.getData(address,amount);
then add that dataforTx to data field?**

> var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx'); var privateKey = new
>   Buffer('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109',
>   'hex')
>
> var rawTx = {   nonce: '0x00',   gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
>   gasLimit: '0x2710',   to:
>   '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',    value: '0x00',
>   ****data:
>   '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
>   }** //how to get hex value of my dataforTx????????**
>
> var tx = new Tx(rawTx); tx.sign(privateKey);
>
> var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
>
> //console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'));
>
> web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'),
>   function(err, hash) {   if (!err)
>       console.log(hash); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385"
>   });

*i am still not able to transfer token.it returns hash value but not reflecting any balance in other account. and if i use balanceOf then how to catch output of balanceOf function in sendRawTransaction*

Answer (score 2):

```
var abi=[//your abi array];

var contractAddress = "//your contract address";

var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);


let send_add = data.send_public_address;

let recv_add = rec_public_address;

let amount = web3.toHex(transfer_amount),

let nonce = web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(send_public_address));

var private_key = privatekey_sender.slice(2);

let gas = web3.toHex(data.gas_limit);

let gasPrice = web3.toHex(data.gas_price);

var rawTx = {

        from: send_add,

        nonce: nonce,

        gasLimit: gas,

        gasPrice: gasPrice,

        amount: web3.toHex(transfer_amount),

        to: recv_add,

    };

var transaction = new tx(rawTx);

var txData = new Buffer(private_key, 'hex');

transaction.sign(txData);

var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');

contract.transfer.sendTransaction(recv_add , amount , {'0x' + serializedTx}, 
function (err, txHash) {

        if (txHash) {

            next(null, txHash);

        }

        else if (err && err.message) {

            next(err.message, null);

        }

        else {

            next('Unable to sendTransaction', null);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation how this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a tutorial for this problem https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto/blob/master/tutorials/signed-data.md#deploy-the-contract

Comment: Link only answer are not recommended because they become useless if the server is down or the page is moved. It is better to include the main points in the answer and only use the link to expand on the details.